# How to merge the cell of single table

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, cell

hi i had a table looks like

```
id      name   value 1   value 2    
1       a        50       NULL  
2       b        NULL     60          
1       a        NULL     80    
2       b        100      NULL
```

now i want to combine the output should be like

```
id  name  value 1   value 2   
1    a      50       80   
2    b     100       60
```

I generated this using view.

Comment: the first table was generated using view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT id,  
       name,  
       [value 1] = MAX([value 1]),   
       [value 2] = MAX([value 2]) 
FROM dbo.YourView
GROUP BY id, name
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2aa96/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: in my view i used union all to combine the data first select statement has value 1 as NULL,in second select statement value 2 is Null.

Comment: Column 'MY_VIEW.VALUE 1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user3035605: i don't know what SQL you have used. Edit your question and show it. Have you also used `[value 1] = MAX([value 1])` to get the `Value 1`?

Comment: @user3035605: but it works as you can see in the demo-link above. So there must be a difference which only you knows. Again, edit your question to provide more informations.